# how to save two rows when two rows are sent and than delete one if just one sent?

Tags: mysql

I am new in mySql. but need to implement next fnx:

Step 1: I save

```
 notificationChannels = ['channel1', 'channel2];
```

I save each channel in separate row.using loop

```
 notificationSettings.notificationChannels.forEach(function (channel) {
            var channelQuery = 'INSERT INTO notification_channels (user_id, channel) VALUES('+ connection.escape(req.session.user_id)+','+ connection.escape(channel)+') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE channel='+connection.escape(channel) ;
            connection.query( channelQuery, function(err, rows) {

                if (!err){
                    isOk = true;
                }
                else{
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        });
```

So I've saved 2 rows.

than I want to change settigns  - save just 1 channel:

```
notificationChannels = ['channel2];
```

So now I need to delete row with 'channel1 and leave just 'channel2'. how to do it?

Comment: `delete from notification_channels where ...`?

Comment: I thought there is some method like delete all except channel2

Comment: `delete from notification_channels where channel <> 'channel2'`

Comment: makes sence. but what if I had: 

       notificationChannels = ['channel1', 'channel2, 'channel3'];

and want  change it to 

     notificationChannels = ['channel1', 'channel2,]

Comment: `delete from notification_channels where channel = 'channel3'` That is really basic stuff. Please take a SQL tutorial.

Comment: ok.thanks will do that!